# SVM on a 1d array

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm messing around with the Titanic dataset. I'm trying to apply an SVM a number of individual features using the following code:

```
quanti_vars = ['Age','Pclass','Fare','Parch']

imp_med = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')
imp_med.fit(titanic[['Age']])

for i in (X_train, X_test):
    i[['Age']] = imp_med.transform(i[['Age']])

svm_clf = SVC()
svm_clf.fit(X_train[quanti_vars], y_train)
y_pred = svm_clf.predict(X_test[quanti_vars])
svm_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
svm_accuracy

for i in quanti_vars:
    svm_clf.fit(X_train[i], y_train)
    y_pred = svm_clf.predict(X_test[i])
    svm_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
    print(i,': ',svm_accuracy)
```

That final `for` loop throws an error of `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead` and I have no idea why--shouldn't an SVM be able to operate on a single feature?

Comment: I can examine the best and worst single-feature classifiers to determine which I should continue using and which are the least effective.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that, very simply, I needed to double-bracket the `i` to subset properly. So:

```
for i in quanti_vars:
    svm_clf.fit(X_train[[i]], y_train)
    y_pred = svm_clf.predict(X_test[[i]])
    svm_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
    print(i,': ',svm_accuracy)
```

produces

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
Age :  0.5874125874125874
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
Pclass :  0.5874125874125874
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
Fare :  0.42657342657342656
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
Parch :  0.6153846153846154
```

(I won't pretend it's good, but at least it works.)

Answer (score 0):

that's easy
just write this instead:

```
y_pred = svm_clf.predict([X_test[i]])
```

adding a [] will convert it to 2D array 
and it's better to band fare to 10 class instead of using it directly
bcs there is a huge difference between 30$ and 50$ but it will fade as it goes up
for example, there isn't too much difference between 300$ and 500$